# How to override magento default welcome message?

Tags: magento

I have the following code written.

My folder structure is :: 
app\code\local\ChangeWelcome\Page (the last two been NameSpace/Module_Name)

my config.xml is

```
<config>
 <modules> 
    <ChangeWelcome_Page> 
        <version >0.1.0 </version > 
    </ChangeWelcome_Page > 
    </modules > 
 <global>
    <page>
        <block>
            <html>
                <rewrite>
                    <item>ChangeWelcome_Page_Block_Html_Header</item>
                </rewrite>
            </html>
        </block>
    </page>
   </global>
 </config>
```

my ChangeWelcome/Page/Block/Html/Header.php is

```
class ChangeWelcome_Page_Block_Html_Header extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header
        {
            public function getWelcome()
            {
               echo "Ok------------1";
            }
        }
```

my app/etc/modules/ChangeWelcome_Page.xml is

```
<config>
      <modules>
    <ChangeWelcome_Page>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </ChangeWelcome_Page>
    </modules>
</config>
```

The module shows up is System - > COnfiguration ->Advanced->Advanced as ChangeWelcome_Page (enabled).

Still nothing happens in the frontend.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks And Regards,
Rupak Banerjee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config.xml is wrong.  It needs to look like this instead...

```
<config>
    <modules> 
        <ChangeWelcome_Page> 
            <version>0.1.0</version> 
        </ChangeWelcome_Page> 
    </modules> 
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_header>ChangeWelcome_Page_Block_Html_Header</html_header>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

If all you want to do is simply change the welcome message though, you can actually do this via the admin area without the need for a module and block rewrite:

```
system > configuration > design > header > welcome text
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the help. That works! Has magento has any documentation to know about how to write config.xml files ?

Comment: You will tend to find bits of info here and there.  Try this for a starting point: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/174/changing_and_customizing_magento_code